# select records that one column are numbers close to 10

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns.
one of them is `[Code]`. I have many records on this table.

I want to select records that their `[Code]` are numbers close to `10` regularly
for example if select records that has `[Code]=9` then select records that has `[Code] = 8` etc...

Comment: not clear enough. not able to get what exaclty you want . show your query

Comment: give some sample data though.

Comment: I haven't any query because I can not to make it

Comment: select * from yourTable where [Code] < 10 order by code desc... that is all i got from your description... put some effort into it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I implement based on your though.

If you wish near record or record-id, not value, then you can change only condition `a.data` to `a.rid`.

```
declare @t table (data int)

insert into @t values(1), (2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(50),(51),(52)

declare @value int = 11 , @getDatToValue int = 2
select * from
(
    select * , ROW_NUMBER( ) over(order by data) rid
    from @t 
)
a
where 
a.data between (@value - @getDatToValue) and (@value + @getDatToValue)
```